# How to attach node js debugger to the local iis in visual studio

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, debugging, websocket, iisnode

I have created a nodejs app using express and I managed to deploy it on iisnode locally. and it is accessible from all machines in the network, so far so good.

Now I'm trying to debug this code remotely in visual studio 2019 so that whenever a request comes to the server I can debug it.
I followed this manual [here](https://medium.com/@bogac/remote-debugging-node-js-apps-on-iis-with-iisnode-setup-for-express-4-part-1-node-inspector-e074163924f1) but now once I try to attach debugger using visual studio I get this error in the picture below. Any Idea how should I fix this?

[image]

Comment: does your server listen/run on port 443 (wss) and not only unsecure http/80 (ws) ?

Comment: @Marc : I'm not sure about that, I just gtt this error

Comment: Dude, its your server... Try `ws://....` as url instead of `wss://...`

Comment: @Marc I changed it But I got: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" this time instead

Comment: @Marc and I think based on my investigation the iis runs on port 80 localhost, but I can not use visual studio debugger to attach the debugger but it actually works with vsCode debugger

Comment: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" Sounds like the IIS (proxy) is not properly configured to proxy websocket connections